# Is a Typescript type possible for deep property `a.b.c` syntax?

Tags: typescript

There are a number of [resources](https://codewithstyle.info/Deep-property-access-in-TypeScript/) on how to do deep property access in a type-safe way. In my application, though, I need to pass around the property key (`'a.b.c'`) as a sort of unique key into the data. I'm not sure how to translate some of those ideas to my case:

```
type Pizza = {
  sauce: string
  cheese: {
    name: string
    stinkiness: number
  }
}

function torgle<R extends Record<string, any>>(
  records: R[], key: keyof R | ???
) { ... }

torgle(pizzas, 'sauce')
torgle(pizzas, 'cheese.stinkiness')
```

In the latest Typescript, is there any type better than `string` that could substitute for `???` here?

Comment: I created a tutorial just for this if you are interested: https://dev.to/pffigueiredo/typescript-utility-keyof-nested-object-2pa3